# Haskellでreactiveをインストールできない

Tags: haskell, reactive-programming, macos

このサイトの「sinwave.hs」をいうのを実行してみたくて、Haskellを導入してみた際の質問です。
http://maoe.hatenadiary.jp/entry/20100123/1264225964

どうもreactiveというライブラリが必要みたいなので、

```
$ cabal install reactive
```

とインストールしてみようとしたのですが、
以下のようなエラーが出てしまいました。

```
Warning: --root-cmd is no longer supported, see
https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/3353 (if you didn't type --root-cmd,
comment out root-cmd in your ~/.cabal/config file)
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring reactive-0.5.0.1...
Building reactive-0.5.0.1...
Failed to install reactive-0.5.0.1
Build log ( /Users/kamesho/.cabal/logs/ghc-8.2.1/reactive-0.5.0.1-CYwyF7YDHygLOkFL84NpWM.log ):
cabal: Entering directory '/var/folders/2f/936bl12n26n3jhgrqwdmbyvc0000gn/T/cabal-tmp-5107/reactive-0.5.0.1'
Configuring reactive-0.5.0.1...
Preprocessing library for reactive-0.5.0.1..
Building library for reactive-0.5.0.1..

src/Data/SFuture.hs:4:16: warning:
    -fglasgow-exts is deprecated: Use individual extensions instead
  |
4 | {-# OPTIONS_GHC -fglasgow-exts #-}
  |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

src/Data/Reactive.hs:6:16: warning:
    -fglasgow-exts is deprecated: Use individual extensions instead
  |
6 | {-# OPTIONS_GHC -fglasgow-exts #-}
  |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[1 of 4] Compiling Data.Fun         ( src/Data/Fun.hs, dist/build/Data/Fun.o )
[2 of 4] Compiling Data.Future      ( src/Data/Future.hs, dist/build/Data/Future.o )

src/Data/Future.hs:58:1: warning: [-Wunused-imports]
    The import of ‘Control.Applicative’ is redundant
      except perhaps to import instances from ‘Control.Applicative’
    To import instances alone, use: import Control.Applicative()
   |
58 | import Control.Applicative
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

src/Data/Future.hs:108:11: warning: [-Wunused-do-bind]
    A do-notation statement discarded a result of type
      ‘ghc-prim-0.5.1.0:GHC.Types.Any’
    Suppress this warning by saying
      ‘_ <- forever $ threadDelay maxBound’
    |
108 |           forever $ threadDelay maxBound
    |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

src/Data/Future.hs:123:17: warning: [-Wunused-do-bind]
    A do-notation statement discarded a result of type ‘ThreadId’
    Suppress this warning by saying ‘_ <- forkIO $ mka >>= sink’
    |
123 |                 forkIO $ mka >>= sink
    |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[3 of 4] Compiling Data.Reactive    ( src/Data/Reactive.hs, dist/build/Data/Reactive.o )

src/Data/Reactive.hs:223:10: error:
    • No instance for (Alternative Event)
        arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
    • In the instance declaration for ‘MonadPlus Event’
    |
223 | instance MonadPlus Event where { mzero = mempty; mplus = mappend }
    |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cabal: Leaving directory '/var/folders/2f/936bl12n26n3jhgrqwdmbyvc0000gn/T/cabal-tmp-5107/reactive-0.5.0.1'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
reactive-0.5.0.1-CYwyF7YDHygLOkFL84NpWM failed during the building phase. The
exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

コードの中にエラーがあるようですが、これではどうしようもなさそうだったので、今度は直接reactiveのコードをダウンロードしてインストールしようと試みました。

まず下のサイトにアクセスして、0.5.0.1のtar.gzをダウンロードします。
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive

そして、展開したディレクトリ内で以下のコマンドを入力します。

```
$ runhaskell Setup.lhs configure
```

すると、以下のような出力になって、configureがうまくいきません。

```
Configuring reactive-0.5.0.1...
Setup.lhs: Encountered missing dependencies:
TypeCompose >=0.6.7
```

TypeComposeというライブラリのバージョンが小さいのかと思ってTypeComposeのバージョンを確認してみましたが、以下のような感じで、バージョンにも問題ないように見えます。

```
$ cabal list --installed
(~省略~)
* TypeCompose
    Synopsis: Type composition classes & instances
    Default available version: 0.9.12
    Installed versions: 0.9.12
    Homepage: https://github.com/conal/TypeCompose
    License:  BSD3
```

何分Haskellを触るのが初めてなもので、いまいちライブラリのインストール方法などが掴みきれてない状態です。

どうしたらreactiveをインストールする事が出来るでしょうか？

ちなみに今の環境は以下の通りです。
パソコン:MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2014)
OS:macOS Sierra Ver. 10.12.6
cabal:
cabal-install version 2.0.0.0
compiled using version 2.0.0.2 of the Cabal library

足りない情報があればぜひお伝えください。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tar.gz ファイルから直接インストールした場合の方法については私も詳しくないのですが、
ここ数年Haskellではパッケージをインストールする際、[stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) というツールを使用するのが一般的になっています。

いろいろ試してみましたが、reactiveは残念ながら2010年が最終更新日と大変古くなっている（その間、GHCの非互換な変更がたくさんありました！）ため、少なくとも問題の記事に載っているサンプルをビルドするのは、stackからインストールできる最もメジャーバージョンが古いGHC（7.8.4, LTS Haskell 2.22）でも不可能でした。

問題の記事に使用したGHCやreactiveパッケージのバージョンが載っていないので、確実なバージョンはわかりませんが、どうしても試したい場合、 https://www.haskell.org/platform/prior.html から古いバージョンのHaskell Platformをインストールするしかなさそうです。

なお、stackについては下記のページも参考にどうぞ。

- https://qiita.com/tanakh/items/6866d0f570d0547df026
- https://qiita.com/igrep/items/da1d8df6d40eb001a561

Comment: 件のブログにおいて使われたバージョンは1つ前のブログ記事である[ここ](http://maoe.hatenadiary.jp/entry/20100116/1263661213)に書いてあるものと同一かもしれません。つまり、GHC 6.12.1、reactive 0.11.4 です。どちらにせよ残念ながら現状 Stack が使えませんね……。

Comment: リンクして頂いた URL からリンクされている古い Haskell Platform がことごとく 404 Not Found になっているようです。[こちらのページ](https://www.haskell.org/platform/prior.html)からでも 404 ですね……。

Comment: @nekketsuuu すみません、検索して適当に見つけたリンクを貼ってしまいました。。。 https://www.haskell.org/platform/prior.html にあったリンクのうち一つ、 https://www.haskell.org/platform/download/2010.2.0.0/haskell-platform-2010.2.0.0.i386.dmg を試したところ404にはなりませんでしたが、どれが404だったのでしょうか。。。？　いずれにしても、リンクは更新しておきます。ありがとうございます！

Comment: あ、本当ですね。見落としていたようです。ありがとうございます。2010.2.0.0 の Source は 404 のようです。また、2010.1.0.0 以下の部分のリンクは全て haskell.org/platform にリダイレクトされてしまいます。この質問本体とは直接関係しませんが、[この issue](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-platform/issues/200) と関連しているようです。

Comment: お二人共、助言頂いてありがとうございます。
なるほど、そうだったんですね・・・残念です。
さすがに古いバージョンをインストールしてまで試す気は無いので、今回は諦めることにします。

stackの事もありがとうございました。右も左も分からないに等しい状態だったので、こういった情報は助かります。

Answer (score 3):

ビルド&実行できるようにしてみました。
https://github.com/waddlaw/reactive-example

Comment: うわっすごい、動きました！ありがとうございます！
これはどうなってるんですか？Reactiveをインストールしたわけじゃないみたいですね。質問内のtar.gzを展開したのと同じファイルが入っていますが、ライブラリをインストールせずにどうにか直接使ってるって感じなんでしょうか？

Comment: 簡単な説明ですが、

今回は、パッケージの依存関係を合わせるのは難しそうだったので、`reactive` の方をコンパイルできるようにソースコードを書き換える方針にしました。

以下のファイルを見てもらうとわかるのですが `reactive` と `unamb` パッケージはローカルのものを参照するように変更してあります。

https://github.com/waddlaw/reactive-example/blob/master/example/stack.yaml


修正方法については、実際に `stack build` してエラーメッセージを見ながら適当に書き換えていく感じです。(`hpack` で少しずつ置き換えながら進めました。)

また、`stack unpack <package>` というコマンドを使えば `Hackage` から `<package>.tar.gz` をダウンロードして展開という作業を自動的に行ってくれるので便利ですよ。

Comment: なるほど、そういう方針で修正したのですね！納得です。unpackコマンドも便利そうですね！是非使わせていただきます。色々と教えてくださってありがとうございました！